# Show selected vale of a dropdown in Html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I have two viewbags `"ViewBag.workSheetNames"` and `"ViewBag.selectedName"`.

`"ViewBag.workSheetNames"` contains option values of dropdown and `"ViewBag.selectedName"` contains the name which has to be shown as selected in dropdown. I am doing this with the given code:--

```
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.workSheetNames)
      {
        if (item == ViewBag.selectedName)
         {
           <option selected="selected">@item</option>
         }
         else
         {
          <option>@item</option>
         }       
       }
```

Please suggest any efficient way to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the HtmlHelpers of Mvc itself to do this. I worked out a small example:

```
@{
    ViewBag.SelectedItem= "2";
    ViewBag.List = new SelectList(
        new List<object>()
        {
            new {Id = 1, Label = "option 1"}, 
            new {Id = 2, Label = "option 2"}
        }, "Id", "Label", ViewBag.SelectedItem);
}

@Html.DropDownList("DropdownListId", (SelectList)ViewBag.List)
```